# Error when using xmlstream reader

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

I am using `xmlstreamreader` in java to read attribute values and other data. This is the xml String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><samlp:AuthnReques
t xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL
="http://localhost:8080/consumer.jsp" **ID="abc"** **IssueInstant="2012-04-14T11:44:49
:796"** ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="
2.0">**<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://loca
lhost:8080/saml/SProvider.jsp</saml:Issuer>**<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2
000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.or
g/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.
org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorith
m="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestM
ethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>VzKYOu1g
ert3DDrNUSO1/Au3PGeD1PEyPuJeI2GO6ec=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><Sign
atureValue>k7hVlbsEhGW5ryelSbrwWWyJq3cdyDuVeQCOqRilbky8hEk/1sHI9DNOvOlPZ7OC9bI4d
EHm46R1
CDXoXkyOoXdq+3M/HbUakHM7eNvF5+j+NUXUX9dijb/rDzq05VNHcSIDXRpvMc1IRBremi0voVqX
ZuHRn+IBeD8hSK1LXsE=</SignatureValue></Signature></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Then I tried to read the attribute ID, IssueInstant and the element Issuer. all the 3 are highlighted(actually between **) in the above string. I have used the following code:

```
while(reader.hasNext()){
    reader.next();
    if(reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT){

        if(reader.getLocalName().equals("AuthnRequest"))
        {
         String ns=reader.getNamespaceURI();
         System.out.println(ns);
         id=reader.getAttributeValue(ns,"ID");

         rec_instant=reader.getAttributeValue(ns,"IssueInstant");



        System.out.println("1"+id);
        System.out.println("2"+rec_instant);

        }
        else if(reader.getLocalName().equals("Issuer"))
        {
         rec_issuer=reader.getElementText();
         System.out.println("4"+reader.getElementText());
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the folowing output:

```
1null
2null
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,436]
Message: parser must be on START_ELEMENT to read next text
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Is that your exact code? I could understand the exception if you'd got an extra brace somewhere...

Comment: @MarkByers : the line right after else if.

Comment: @JonSkeet : yes this is the exact code. why do you ask?

Comment: @Ashwin: For exactly the reason I stated: if you'd got an extra closing brace so that your `else` was actually associated with the *first* `if` rather than the `second`, it would explain everything.

Comment: @JonSkeet : No actually the brackets are correctly placed and "else if" is for the inner "if" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marko suggests, the exception is due to calling `getElementText()` twice in a row.

If I change this:

```
String rec_issuer=reader.getElementText();
System.out.println("4"+reader.getElementText());
```

to this:

```
String rec_issuer = reader.getElementText();
System.out.println("4" + rec_issuer);
```

then I get the following output:

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol
1null
2null
4http://localhost:8080/saml/SProvider.jsp
```

If I *also* change the `getAttributeValue` calls to use `null` instead of `ns`, like this:

```
String id = reader.getAttributeValue(null,"ID");    
String rec_instant = reader.getAttributeValue(null,"IssueInstant");
```

I get:

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol
1abc
22012-04-14T11:44:49:796
4http://localhost:8080/saml/SProvider.jsp
```

That's using your original XML.

Comment: can you just help me, out of curiosity. I'm reading the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) and I don't see getAttributeValue. Where should I look?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: You're looking at XMLEventReader - it's in XMLStreamReader.

Comment: @JonSkeet : You are dead right about using reader.getElementText() twice. Thanks. But honestly using reader.getAttributeValue(null,"ID"); still prints null. I don't understand why.

Comment: @Ashwin: Well it didn't when I tried it - I wouldn't have posted that output without trying it. I can post a short but complete program to demonstrate that when I get home. Note that it would have made life easier if you'd formatted the XML in a cut-and-paste friendly way.

Comment: @JonSkeet :Sorry about that. But did you try the reader.getAttributeValue(null,"ID") on the first xmldoc or the second one.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Sorry dude..just CHILLLL. It woks fine now. I will accept your answer:)

Answer (score 2):

You are using ns for the attributes, but the attributes are in fact in the null ns (they have no namespace). As for the exception, you are calling `getElementText` twice. This method is not a pure getter, it also advances the reader to the end element (as per its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getElementText%28%29)).

Comment: okay.. I tried with putting the "null" instead of ns. Still getting the same output.

Comment: @Ashwin: Did you use "null" instead of a null reference though? See my answer for working code.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik : see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html for the api.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik : thanks for pointing out the exception reason. I have corrected it. But still hte null value problem persists.